# Check if any element of Eigen::Matrix is different from zero

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen, any

I have an `Eigen::Matrix<double, Dynamic, Dynamic>`, and I need to check if any of its elements is different from 0.

I tried the following code:

```
Matrix<double, Dynamic, Dynamic> m;
bool f = (m != 0.0).any();
```

But I got a compiler error.

> Invalid operands to binary expression ('const Eigen::Matrix' and 'double')

Comment: not related to the error, but you should compare floating points to zero via `(abs(m) < eps)`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Eigen, most of the element-wise operations are handled by an [`Array`](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1Array.html) class. Fortunately, there is a simple way to use them on `Matrix` objects. Try

```
bool f = (m.array() != 0.0).any();
```

Comment: Does the array() method create a new object? I am concerned about performance.

Comment: Nope. It just treats the existing object as an Array.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is

```
bool f = !m.isZero();
```

It should work for both `Array` and `Matrix`